# WooCommerce Dynamic Pricing Plugin API

Tags: wordpress, rest, woocommerce

Im currently making use of the [WooCommerce Dynamic Pricing plugin](https://woocommerce.com/products/dynamic-pricing/) and trying to find a way to add some basic pricing groups via the API. I havent been able to find any information on the API, so Im hoping somewhere can lead me in the right direction.

Currently trying to just adding values in the meta key, but nothing seems to add.

All im trying to do is create a basic pricing group on a product but stuck in trying to find any info for the API letalone how to apply it

any tips greatly appreciated

```
{
  "data": {
    "name": "Test Product",
    "type": "simple",
    "backorders_allowed": "true",
    "managing_stock": "true",
    "stock_quantity": " 0",
    "in_stock": "true",
    "sku": " #992875",
    "weight": " 0.16",
    "height": " ",
    "width": " ",
    "depth": " ",
    "regular_price": " 137.35",
    "sale_price": " ",
    "description": "A short Description of the item",
    "short_description": "Long Description of the item",
    "meta": [
    {
        "key":"pricing_rules",
        "value":"unauthenticated"
    }
    ],
    "categories": [
      {
        "name": "Equipment"
      }
    ],
    "variations": []
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

worked it out.

All I had to do was a get of an existing item with all the parameters populated and then make use of those and post them back in as it provided all the keys.

removing the key id ensured a new set of records were created.

Comment: Can you share some sample code on this? I am working on the exact same issue. Thanks.